# vim in Macbook Pro command line doesn't work appropriately

Tags: macos, vim

I just switched from a Windows laptop to a Macbook Pro. I have installed vim and macvim using homebrew. Everything works fine with macvim, but in the command line, the vim exhibits weird behaviors.

First, the cursor in the Insert mode (which I suppose should be simply a line) is the same as the Normal mode (which is a rectangle), making it impossible to tell the current mode from the cursor shape. I don't know whether this is normal with vim in the command line because I didn't pay attention before. But this is certainly different from the behavior of macvim and it helps to distinguish the shapes of the cursor in different modes.

Second, the backspace does not work appropriately. It often cannot delete letters in the Insert mode.

I am totally new to OS X, so I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give some hints on how to solve these issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in your question is related to Mac OS X or any operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, nothing in your question relates in any way to Mac OS X.

I also like my cursor to change shape when in insert mode, and I use these lines to make it happen in iTerm2:

```
let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"
```

This is a hack, and YMMV depending on which terminal emulator you're using. I suggest googling to find the best solution for your case.

The weird backspace behavior you're experiencing is caused by one of the notorious Vim defaults. Simply set

```
set backspace=eol,start,indent
```

to make it work as expected.

I suggest starting with or at least skim through Tim Pope's [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

When run in a terminal emulator, Vim has no control over the shape of the cursor. Some hacks exist but they only "work" by chance so I would suggest you get used to it and read `:help 'showmode'`.

Your backspace issue with a simple option. See `:help 'backspace'`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. This clarifies things.